# regex match two words based on a matching substring

Tags: regex, grouping

there are 4 strings as shown below

```
ABC_FIXED_20220720_VALUEABC.csv
ABC_FIXED_20220720_VALUEABCQUERY_answer.csv
ABC_FIXED_20220720_VALUEDEF.csv
ABC_FIXED_20220720_VALUEDEFQUERY_answer.csv
```

Two strings are considered as matched based on a matching substring value (VALUEABC, VALUEDEF in the above shown strings). Thus I am looking to match first 2 (having VALUEABC) and then next 2 (having VALUEDEF). The matched strings are identified based on the same value returned for one regex group.

What I tried so far

`ABC.*[0-9]{8}_(.*[^QUERY_answer])(?:QUERY_answer)?.csv`

This returns regex group-1 (from **(.*[^QUERY_answer])**) value "VALUEABC" for first 2 strings and "VALUEDEF" for next 2 strings and thus desired matching achieved.

But the problem with above regex is that as soon as the value ends with any of the characters of "QUERY_answer", the regex doesn't match any value for the grouping. For instance, the below 2 strings doesn't match at all as the VALUESTU ends with "U" here :

```
ABC_FIXED_20220720_VALUESTU.csv
ABC_FIXED_20220720_VALUESTUQUERY_answer.csv
```

I tried to use Negative Lookahead:

```
ABC.*[0-9]{8}_(.*(?!QUERY_answer))(?:QUERY_answer)?.csv
```

but in this case the grouping-1 value is returned as "VALUESTU" for first string and "VALUESTUQUERY_answer" for second string, thus effectively making the 2 strings unmatched.

Any way to achieve the desired matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
ABC.*[0-9]{8}_(.*?)(?:QUERY_answer)?\.csv
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OtQyKS/1).

**Note**

- `.*[^QUERY_answer]` matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then any one char other than `Q`, `U`, `E`, etc., i.e. any char in the negated character class. This is replaced with `.*?`, to match any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible.
- `(?:QUERY_answer)?` - the group is made non-capturing to reduce grouping complexity.
- `\.csv` - the `.` is escaped to match a literal dot.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following regex.

```
^ABC_[^_]*_[0-9]+_(.*?)(?:QUERY_answer)?\.csv$
```

***OR*** to match exact 8 digits try:

```
^ABC_[^_]*_[0-9]{8}_(.*?)(?:QUERY_answer)?\.csv$
```

Here is the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/7BoabM/1) for above regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^ABC_[^_]*_        ##Matching from starting of value ABC followed by _ till next occurrence of _.
[0-9]+_            ##Matching continuous occurrences of digits followed by _ here.
(.*?)              ##Creating one and only capturing group using lazy match which is opposite of greedy match.
(?:QUERY_answer)?  ##In a non-capturing group matching QUERY_answer and keeping it optional.
\.csv$             ##Matching dot literal csv at the end of the value.
```